# Convert base64 encoded password to SecureString using powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, base64, securestring

Unable to authenticate with active directory after password is set from base64 decoded password.

Long story short, I'm sending commands via winRM to a remote windows system from Rundeck (linux). This is part of our automation platform.

The issue begins with sending passwords, which can have special characters that cause linux/windows to be unhappy in different and unique ways. So I decided to base64 encode the password before sending it to the remote script.
This seemed to work, all tests output the password just as it was encoded and the `convertTo-SecurePassword` accepted the string.

However, after attempting to log into active directory with the new user account, it fails.
If I use the ADUC gui tool to set the password, using the same password I originally encoded to base64, I can authenticate.

**base64 password**:
LS0yMHxIaWdofE5lcnZlfFN0YXl8MTctLQo=

**plain text password**:
--20|High|Nerve|Stay|17--

```
function get-creds([String]$pass){
  try{
    $localPass = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($pass.Trim()))
    $localSecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $localPass -AsPlainText -Force

    # Validate secure password
    $Ptr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToCoTaskMemUnicode($localSecurePass)
    $result = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringUni($Ptr)
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ZeroFreeCoTaskMemUnicode($Ptr)

    Write-Host "Password: $localPass"
    Write-Host "Secure Password: $result"
    Write-Host ($localPass -eq $result)

    return $localSecurePass
  }
  catch{
    "Could not create secure password from passwd"
    $_
  }
}

function create-user([string]$fName, [string]$lName, [String]$samAccountName, [String]$pass, [string]$ou, [string]$company, [string]$department){
  $localPass = get-creds $pass
  $localOu = $ou.Replace(":", ",")
  $localCompany = $company -ireplace [regex]::Escape("none"), ""
  $localDepartment = $department -ireplace [regex]::Escape("none"), ""
  $localDepartment = $localDepartment.Replace(":", " ")

  try{
    New-ADUser -Enabled $True -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -AccountPassword $localPass -DisplayName "$fName $lName" -GivenName $fName -Surname $lName -Name $samAccountName -SamAccountName $samAccountName -UserPrincipalName $samAccountName@taosengineering.io -Path "$localOu,DC=taosengineering,DC=local" -Department "$localDepartment" -Company $localCompany -Verbose
    if ($?){
      Write-Host "$samAccountName created successfully"
      Write-Host
      Write-Host =============================================
      Write-Host "fName: $fName"
      Write-Host "lName: $lName"
      Write-Host "samAccountName: $samAccountName"
      Write-Host "ou: $localOu"
      Write-Host "company: $localCompany"
      Write-Host "department: $localDepartment"
      Write-Host =============================================
      Write-Host
    }
  }
  catch{
    "An error occurred while creating user account."
    $_
    exit $?
  }
}
```

```
Password: --20|High|Nerve|Stay|17--
Secure Password: --20|High|Nerve|Stay|17--
True
```

I've tried both `[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString` and `[System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString` thinking it was an encoding issue, but same result.

Comment: How long are you waiting after creating the account to attempt a login? Is it possible, the new account hasn't been replicated to the domain controller you're authenticating against yet? The code in `get-creds` looks fine.

Comment: `Write-Host ($localPass -eq $localSecurePass)` will always return $false, because `$localPass` is of type String, while `$localSecurePass` is a SecureString. Perhaps you wanted to do `Write-Host ($localPass -eq $result)` ? May I also suggest you use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) for cmdlets like `New-ADUser` that take so many parameters.

Comment: @Theo Yes, ment that to be ($localPass -eq $result). Updated.

Comment: Does the string `--20|High|Nerve|Stay|17--` convert to base64 the same on both Windows and your Linux machine? It could be the character encoding used by default on Windows is different than the one used on Linux.

Comment: Yeah, they seem indistinguishable. Plus, on the PS side converting it to a ASCII or UTF8 string should take care of any discrepancies. I've honestly never ran into this situation before. I use bash/python for almost everything. I've b64 encoded many a string and sent them to remote systems via one transport method or another. However, never with windows/PS/WinRM in the mix.